# Null pointer Exception while using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sql, listview, simplecursoradapter

I would like to get some data from my database...
I'm using the SimpleCursorAdapter to transmit the data to a list view but I get a NullPointer Exception here is the LogCat:

```
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at       .diamond.clickers.Shop.populateListViewFromDB(Shop.java:104)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at com.diamond.clickers.Shop.onCreateView(Shop.java:51)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1777)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1106)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:690)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1571)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-01 17:26:42.048: E/Shop(26288):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my code:

```
void populateListViewFromDB() {

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
    // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);
    //if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
        //  do {
        // do what you need with the cursor here


    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
            {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.KEY_PRICE,DBAdapter.KEY_LEVEL,DBAdapter.KEY_ART,DBAdapter.KEY_VALUETXT,DBAdapter.KEY_PIC };
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.tv_Shop_item1,     R.id.tv_Shop_Price_item1,R.id.tv_shop_Level_item1,R.id.tv_shop_use_item1,R.id.tv_shop_use_item2,R.id.IV_Shop_item1 };

    // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),      // Context
                    R.layout.item_shop, // Row layout template
                    cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                    toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                    );

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView myList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewShop);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
     //  } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
    //}
}
```

Comment: What is on line 104 of Shop.java?

Comment: 'myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);'

Comment: yes it is in fragment...what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewShop)
```

Assuming the listview is in the fragment layout, it isn't yet a part of the activity view hierarchy in a method called from activity `onCreateView()`.

Pass the view hierarchy you've inflated in `onCreateView()` as the root view you call `findViewById()` on to find views there.

Comment: hmmm also also tried this before but it doent work...but now it do...interesting..But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change the call of `populateListViewFromDB()` from `onCreateView` to `onActivityCreated` and it should work. Also make sure `R.id.listViewShop` is in the same layout as the one that you're inflating on onCreateView.